# AngularJS project works in IE and but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Weird things happened to me. An `AngularJS` project works OK in `IE9`, but not in `Chrome` `35.0.1916.153` . Then I start to debug into Angularjs' source code, found the problem at '**replace**' code returns different result:

```
html.replace(XHTML_TAG_REGEXP, "<$1></$2>")
```

(line 2266 of Angularjs source code at the version i am using)

this works correctly in `IE`, but wrong in `Chrome`.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

**Update1:**

Sorry guys, when I am narrowing down the problem, it is actually not at the 'Replace' Code. It happened at

```
tmp.innerHTML = 'my directive html template'.
```

My template is like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
      <matrixheader> 
      </matrixheader>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <matrixrows> 
      </matrixrows>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

'matrixheader' and 'matrixrows' are 2 directives, which I use them to create table column headers and table rows dynamically.

When AngularJS assigns this template to tmp.innerHTML, in IE after this assignment, template.innerHTML is just what it is, but in Chrome it will become:

```
<matrixheader> 
</matrixheader>
<matrixrows> 
</matrixrows>
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then Angularjs will throw an exception:

```
 Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'matrix' must have exactly one root element. partials/matrix.html
```

Comment: what do you mean words different ?

Comment: works in IE, but not in Chrome. you mean 'works'?, instead of 'words'?

Comment: it's not enough when you say it's work differently, there shouldn't be any change between them, let us know what works different or push your code to plunker / fiddler so we can try it on our own browsers